# How to rank values in a pair from 0 to 1? (without using C++11 or above)

Tags: c++, ranking

I have a map of type

```
map <unsigned, vector < pair <unsigned, float> > > group
```

When printed out, the `float` part is ranked and the data looks like so:

**Raw data**

```
0 43 0
0 3690 0
0 5085 62
0 6085 63
0 977 121
0 4138 142
1 1515 0
1 2863 0
1 6593 64
1 252 96
1 2887 141
```

I am trying to now rank the `float` part (third column from the printing) from 0 to 1, such that the processed data looks like so:

**Processed data**

```
0 43 0
0 3690 0
0 5085 0.4
0 6085 0.6
0 977 0.8
0 4138 1
1 1515 0
1 2863 0
1 5593 0.4
1 6593 0.6
1 252 0.8
1 2887 1
```

I have implemented some rankings before, but never on a `pair` and never from 0 - 1 (usually from 0 to the size of the vector).

Any guides or solutions will be much appreciated, as I feel quite lost on how to approach it.

Comment: max_element (with custom comparator to check .second) and then for_each?

Comment: Why not simply iterate the map to find the highest value of  the third column, and use it on a second pass to compute the normalized value?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Because I am not sure how to write it. I guess whichever way I it's approached, it needs to find the highest value and sift it's way through afterwards.

Comment: @Borgleader I am not sure I understood your proposition.

Comment: Use [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to compare the pairs to find the one which has the highest value (in .second, i.e. 3rd column) and then run a [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) to normalize the values.

Comment: Is it ok not to use a map?

Comment: What sort of `pair`? If you're using C++03?

Comment: Search for the term "normalisation" (not "ranking").

Comment: _"never from 0 - 1 (usually from 0 to the size of the vector)"_ Do you think the approach will be substantially different?

Comment: I'm confused - isn't this just a case of foreach item in the map, std::sort the second item in the iterator?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what is the exact ranking algorithm you wanted to use, but here's a starting point for you:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>


typedef std::pair<unsigned, float> Pair;
typedef std::vector<Pair> Vec;
typedef std::map<unsigned, Vec> Group;

bool pairLess(Pair const & a, Pair const & b) {
    return (a.second < b.second)
        || (!((a.second < b.second) || (b.second < a.second))
            && (a.first < b.first));
}

void rankGroup(Group & g) {
    for (Group::iterator it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
        if (it->second.empty())
            continue;
        /// \todo handle case with one element?
        Vec & v(it->second);

        /// \todo Substitute for actual ranking algorithm:
        Vec::iterator maxIt(std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), &pairLess));
        for (Vec::iterator it2 = v.begin(); it2 != v.end(); ++it2)
            /// \todo handle division by zero:
            it2->second = it2->second / maxIt->second;
    }
}
```

Code for testing:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Group const & g) {
    for (Group::const_iterator it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it) {
        unsigned key = it->first;
        Vec const & v(it->second);
        for (Vec::const_iterator it2 = v.begin(); it2 != v.end(); ++it2)
            os << key << ' ' << it2->first << ' ' << it2->second << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}

void groupAdd(Group & g, unsigned key, unsigned u, float f)
{ g[key].push_back(Pair(u, f)); }

int main() {
    Group input;
    groupAdd(input, 0, 43, 0);
    groupAdd(input, 0, 3690, 0);
    groupAdd(input, 0, 5085, 62);
    groupAdd(input, 0, 6085, 63);
    groupAdd(input, 0, 977, 121);
    groupAdd(input, 0, 4138, 142);
    groupAdd(input, 1, 1515, 0);
    groupAdd(input, 1, 2863, 0);
    groupAdd(input, 1, 6593, 64);
    groupAdd(input, 1, 252, 96);
    groupAdd(input, 1, 2887, 141);
    std::cout << "INPUT:\n" << input << std::endl;

    rankGroup(input);
    std::cout << "RESULT:\n" << input << std::endl;
}
```